# How can I split my dataset in training/validation/test set when the dataset is a cell array?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am training an Elman network (a specific type of Recurrent Neural Network) and for that reason my datasets (input/target) need to be cell arrays (so that the examples are considered as a sequence by the train function).

But, I don't manage to trigger the use of a validation and test set by the train function.

Here is an example, where I want a validation and test set to be used but the train function is not using any (I know that by looking at the performance plot from the 'nntraintool' wizard or by looking at the content of the 'tr' variable in my example below). It seems the "divideind" property and indexes are ignored.

```
%% Set the parameters of the run
n_neurons = 50;         % Number of neurons
n = 1000;               % Total number of samples
ne = 500;               % Number of epochs

%% Create the samples
% Allocate memory
u = zeros(1, n);
x = zeros(1, n);
y = zeros(1, n);

% Initialize u, x and y
u(1)=randn; 
x(1)=rand+sin(u(1));
y(1)=x(1);

% Calculate the samples
for i=2:n
    u(i)=randn;
    x(i)=.8*x(i-1)+sin(u(i));
    y(i)=x(i);
end

%% Create the datasets
X=num2cell(u); 
T=num2cell(y);

%% Train and simulate the network
% Create the net and apply the selected parameters
net = newelm(X,T,n_neurons);        % Create network
net.trainParam.epochs = ne;         % Number of epochs

%% This seems to be ignored
net.divideFcn = 'divideind';
net.divideParam.trainInd = 1:800;
net.divideParam.valInd = 801:900;
net.divideParam.testInd = 901:1000;

[net,tr]= train(net,X,T);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I need to add:

```
  net.divideMode = 'time';
```

so that cell arrays can be divided in train/validation/test sets, for example with:

```
  net.divideFcn = 'divideind';
```